# How to remove the parallelepiped that encloses the writing or make it invisible?

Tags: regions, mesh

I have this code that I found somewhere and I love what it does, I've been checking the "line" command to remove the line or make it invisible but I can't get it, and the other part of the code controls the angle of presentation. Thanks in advance.

```
 region1 = 
  RegionProduct[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["Fally", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1], MeshRegion[{{0}, {2}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];

region2 = 
  RegionProduct[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["Mol", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1], MeshRegion[{{0}, {2}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];

region2Rotated = 
  TransformedRegion[region2, RotationTransform[Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}]];

region2RotatedTranslated = 
  TransformedRegion[region2Rotated, TranslationTransform[{22, 0, 3}]];

RegionPlot3D[{region1, region2RotatedTranslated}]
```

Comment: you mean `RegionPlot3D[{region1, region2RotatedTranslated}, Boxed -> False]`?

Comment: @kglr_wow, thank you very much, the truth is that I did not think that this command would remove the box, so do not look in the bibliography this command, on the other hand as it controls the angle of presentation of the written.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

region1 = RegionProduct[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["Fally", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    _Text, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],
   MeshRegion[{{0}, {2}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
region2 = RegionProduct[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["Mol", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    _Text, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],
   MeshRegion[{{0}, {2}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];

Manipulate[
 region2Rotated =
  TransformedRegion[region2,
   RotationTransform[theta Degree, {1, 0, 0}]];
 region2RotatedTranslated =
  TransformedRegion[region2Rotated,
   TranslationTransform[{22, 0, 3}]];
 RegionPlot3D[{region1, region2RotatedTranslated},
  Boxed -> False],
 {{theta, 90, "rotation angle\n(degrees)"}, 0, 360, 15,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: _maybe I express myself badly, it is not the angle of presentation of the written letters, it is the angle of presentation of the complete text, that is, from the front, from the top, from the left to the right, etc. I do not know if it is understood